# In tornado database module does execute_lastrowid(...) work fine with concurrency?

Tags: python, mysql, concurrency, tornado

I am writing a server application using [Tornado web server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/). Application works with a MySQL database through `tornado.database` module. In the DB there is a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    txt VARCHAR(256)
);
```

As a reaction on certain queries I need to write a new record to this table and return the `id` of newly created record to client. So in the server code I have these lines:

```py
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r'/somequery', queryHandler)]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)
        self.db = tornado.database.Connection(
            host="localhost", database="sampledb",
            user="sampleuser", password="samplepassword")
```

and a handler:

```py
class queryHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        lastid = self.db.execute_lastrowid("INSERT INTO \
                                            SampleTable (txt) \
                                            VALUES('some text');")
        print lastid
```

As far as I know, `tornado.database` is a relatively simple wrapper around `MySQLdb` python module, which guarantees correct work of last row id for each connection only. In my case there is only one connection for the whole applcation.

So, in case of several concurrent client queries to `/somequery` is it possible that last row id would mess between clients or tornado takes care of it?

I tried looking into [source](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/database.html) of `tornado.database`, but found nothing regarding my question.

If this wouldn't work fine, how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute_lastrowid` (actually `tornado.database` in general) is not asynchronous, that is, it will block your application.

So, you won't get the id from another client's request, but if one insert takes a long time, other clients will have to wait for it.

Not related to your question, but typically data changes (e.g. INSERT) should not be accessible via GET requests. Use POST instead.

Comment: Changed to `post`. This is not actual code, just for illustrative purposes. Where I can find information on how asynchronous and synchronous operations are mixed in tornado?

Comment: Good question. It looks like there's nothing in the tornado.database docs about it, really. It is discussed a bit on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/9a08f5f08cdab108           Other then that, the overview (http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html) and the source code.